# Multi-GPU Inference on Pytorch Unet Segmentation Model Not Using Two Gpu

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using two Nvidia-Quadro 1200(4gb) gpu for inferencing an image of size(1024*1792) in UNET segmentation using Pytorch Dataparallel method. Even though the code will start the inference it will go to only one gpu and other will remain idle. Since it is only going to single gpu I am getting the CUDA OOM error every time. I cant compromise the image size because it will alter our objective. I will add the code below. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np
from model import build_unet
from torch.nn.parallel import DataParallel
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
checkpoint_path = "Weights/best_model.pth"

def mask_parse(mask):
    mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
    mask = np.concatenate(\[mask, mask, mask\], axis=-1)  
    return mask

def inference_with_dataparallel(model, cv_img, imname):
    image = cv_img
    imageCopy = image.copy()
    x = np.transpose(image, (2, 0, 1))
    x = x / 255.0
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    x = torch.from_numpy(x)
    x = x.to(device)
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        pred_y = model(x)
        pred_y = torch.sigmoid(pred_y)
    
        pred_y = pred_y[0].cpu().numpy()
        pred_y = np.squeeze(pred_y, axis=0)
        pred_y = pred_y > 0.1  # 0.15
        pred_y = np.array(pred_y, dtype=np.uint8)
    
        pred_y = mask_parse(pred_y)
        out = pred_y * 255
    
        imageCopy = cv2.resize(imageCopy, (mWidth, mHeight))
        out = cv2.resize(out, (mWidth, mHeight))
        finalOut = cv2.addWeighted(imageCopy, 0.6, out, 0.4, 0)
    
        cv2.imwrite('Output/' + imname, finalOut)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = build_unet()
    device = torch.device("cuda")  
    model = model.to(device)
    model = DataParallel(model)
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(checkpoint_path,map_location="cuda"))
    dirListCSV=os.listdir('TestImages')

    for allCSV in tqdm(dirListCSV):
        imgName = 'TestImages/'+ allCSV
        cv_img = cv2.imread(imgName)
        mHeight, mWidth = cv_img.shape[0], cv_img.shape[1]
        cv_img = cv2.resize(cv_img, (1024, 1792))
        inference_with_dataparallel(model, cv_img, allCSV)
        print('Gpu0:',torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(device=device_ids[0]))
        print('Gpu1:',torch.cuda.max_memory_allocated(device=device_ids[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataParallel` splits the input across the batch dimension (see [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html)). This means if you are running inference on a single image at a time, the full input is going to one GPU.

You need [FSDP](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/FSDP_tutorial.html) to shard the model across multiple GPUs.